# How to get Chrome extension to grab and save an image, permanently caching it?

Tags: html, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I am building an extension for Chrome. Is there a way of grabbing an image from a URL and write it in local storage, so that the extension can display the image even when the user is not online?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can encode it in base64 ([here the function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/934012/get-image-data-in-javascript)), and then storing the result in localstorage, for example.

Comment: Thanks, that's really helpful... I can see how to convert an image into a string and save it in local storage. Now call me thick, but how do I then turn that string back into an image object and display it on the screen?

Comment: Using the data-uri scheme ([http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#Inclusion_in_HTML_or_CSS_using_PHP]). myImgElement.src= localStorage.myStoredImage; You have to be careful: at the end of the function, the "header" of the image is removed ( data:image/jpg;base64, ). It's necessay because you'll turn the data-uri back.

Comment: not necessary* or you can also add the mime when you want to retrieve your image : myImgElement.src= "data:image/jpg;base64," + localStorage.myStoredImage;